# Finding a sequence of continuous functions that tend to a nondecreasing function on a close interval

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a nondecreasing real valued function on $[0,1]$,is there a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, such that for each x in the $[0,1]$,
                          $$ f_n(x)\to f(x) \quad \text{ as }\; n\to \infty?$$

P.S. My initial idea is to construct a Riemann integral of $f(x)$ which should be continuous but I fail to find the sequence of functions that will tend to $f(x)$.

Comment: You will need that $f$ is left-continuous, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f(x)=f(a)$ for each $a$

Comment: What about considering $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ over $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ over $[0,1]$.

$f_n(x)$ is clearly non decreasing over that interval ($\frac{a}{n} \geq \frac{b}{n})$ for $a \geq b$).

$f_n(x)$ are also clearly continuous on $[0,1]$.

To show $\frac{x}{n} \to f(x)$ where the limiting function is just the constant function 0 (which is also continuous and non decreasing), let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a natural number $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ which exists by the Archimedean property so that $\frac{x}{n} \leq \frac{x}{N} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer. For n=2 we connect f(0),f(0,5) and f(1) using lines. For n=3 we connect f(0),f(1/4),f(1/2),f(3/4),f(1) by lines. Keep doing that . Since f(x) is monotonic we can show that wach fn(x) is continuous. As n tends to infinity, the fn(x) also tends to f(x).